# inherit class type of constructor argument

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pydantic

I have a pydantic class, let's say class A

I want to use a root_validator on the class and I want intelliense to help me type out the class fields

so I type the values argument as 'Self' to get the intellisense, but intellisense assumes the fields of values are dot accessible, so I wrap my values in a 'dotdict' class that allows me to access them this way

the problem is that mypy complains that my dotdict class doesn't have an attribute X on every access I make

QUESTION: how do I make a instance of the dotdict class inherit the type of the argument passed to the constructor?

```py
# myclasses.py
from mytools import dotdict
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from typing_extensions import Self

class A(BaseModel):
  a: int
  b: str

  @root_validator
  def validateA(cls, values: Self): # type: ignore[valid-type]
    """
    Pylance complains about the type for 'values' being unknown
    'values' is a dictionary with the fields of the class, so I type it as Self

    Pylance is satisfied with this and ONLY NOW provides intellisense for 'values'
    (notice my main goal is to get intellisense, but I also prefer the dot notation)
    
    problem is that intellisense recons the fields of the class are dot accessible
    so I wrap 'values' with the 'dotdict' class to make them dot accessible
    THIS causes one big problem:
    mypy complains on every 'values.field' like this: 
    "class 'dotdict' doesn't have an attribute 'field'
    """
    values = dotdict(values) # type: ignore[valid-type]
    assert values.a == int(values.b) , "simple assertion for show purposes"
    return values
```

```py
# mytools.py
class dotdict(dict): # type: ignore
    """
    a dictionary that supports dot notation and returns 'None' on missing keys
    """
    def __getattr__(self, key: str):
        try:
            v: Optional[Any] = self[key]
            return v
        except KeyError as ke:
            return None
```

One final note, mypy complains about using 'Self' as a type hint, thus the # type: ignore, but I didn't find any solution to this

Thank You!

Edit: "why are You so desperate for intellisense"
"why don't You just copy Your class as a TypedDict to use that for intellisense"

Very disappointed by these comments. If You want to throw ideas around that's fine, but don't undermine the question and offer answers to questions I didn't ask

I have big models, I have big root_validators, maybe I can make other design choices to reduce their size but the only problem I have right now is the mypy throws a "dotdict doesn't have attribute " on EACH ACCESS, I don't wanna add a # type: ignore comment on each access

I noticed if I don't suppress the error that mypy throws bc I type 'values' as Self then it doesn't throw the "dotdict attribute" errors, so I'm just gonna live with that mypy erro (once pero root_validator) and keep typing my values as Self. Apparently it'll solve itself in the next release (as per one of the comments)

Thanks for nothing

Comment: Why are you annotating that parameter with `Self`, I don't understand

Comment: "how do I make a instance of the dotdict class inherit the type of the argument passed to the constructor?" This question doesn't.make much sense. It really isn't clear toe what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: `a: Dict[str, Any] = A(foo="bar")` I don't understand this, `A` is not a dict, why are you annotating it as such?

Comment: You can't use `typing[_extensions].Self` in `mypy` yet (or you'll have to use the `master` branch). It'll be available in the next release.

Comment: None of this makes any sense. The entire premise is just silly. The `values` argument to a `root_validator` method will **always** be a dictionary, specifically `dict[str, Any]`. Annotating it as anything else is ridiculous because you are not the one calling that method. The Pydantic internals are. And those **will always** pass a dictionary to that method.

Comment: Not to mention that you are putting the cart before the horse by even trying to turn `values` into an instance of the class you are supposedly validating against. Just deal with the `dict` normally and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in a comment, you don't control the type of `values`. It will always be a dictionary. But if you are really that desperate for those IntelliSense auto-suggestions, you can always create your own [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) to mirror the actual model and annotate `values` with that.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from typing import TypedDict


class DictA(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str


class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str

    @root_validator
    def validate_stuff(cls, values: DictA) -> DictA:
        ...
        return values
```

If you then try doing something like `values["a"].` inside the method, your IDE should give you a selection of `int` methods and attributes. Note that if your validator is `pre=True` or you are allowing arbitrary extra values, then that annotation is still a lie and the dictionary can contain whatever.

But again, I don't see the point of this. You can always just selectively [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the values you are actually using in the validator in intermediary variables, if you are doing complex stuff with them. There should hardly be a need to have your IDE know the types of *all* the fields.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from typing import Any, cast


class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str

    @root_validator
    def validate_stuff(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        val_a, val_b = cast(int, values["a"]), cast(str, values["b"])
        ...
        return values
```

But even that seems over the top. I cannot imagine a validator being so complex that you really need that.